# Sum a sum in sql

Tags: sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

Good Morning, I am very new to sql and apologies if this is a stupid question

I am trying to calculate the sum of the totalcredit - totaldebit by getting an error.  if I remove the sum(sum line I get a calculation result for totaldebit and totalcredit) but I need to go one step further.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell be where I am going wrong please

````
       Sum(CASE WHEN dbt_crt = 'D' THEN sec_amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalDebit,
       Sum(CASE WHEN  dbt_crt = 'C' THEN sec_amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalCredit,
       sum(sum(TotalDebit) - sum(TotalCredit)))
    FROM test_securities_trans
    group by client_acc, sec_isin
    
    Started executing query at Line 207
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
    Incorrect syntax near ')'.
    Total execution time: 00:00:00.011 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compute the difference on the same row, so there is no need for nesting aggregate functions. You can simply add another conditional sum, like so:

```
sum(case when dbt_crt = 'c' then sec_amount else -sec_amount end) as totaldiff
```

This assumes than `'C'` and `'D'` are the only possible values (otherwise you would need another `WHEN` branch rather than `ELSE`). You can be more explicit about that with a `WHERE` clause:

```
select client_acc, sec_isin,
   sum(case when dbt_crt = 'D' then sec_amount else 0 end) as totaldebit,
   sum(case when dbt_crt = 'C' then sec_amount else 0 end) as totalcredit,
   sum(case when dbt_crt = 'C' then sec_amount else -sec_amount end) as totaldiff
from test_securities_trans
where dbt_crt in ('C', 'D')
group by client_acc, sec_isin
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the expressions:

```
   Sum(CASE WHEN dbt_crt = 'D' THEN sec_amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalDebit,
   Sum(CASE WHEN dbt_crt = 'C' THEN sec_amount ELSE 0 END) as TotalCredit,
   Sum(CASE WHEN dbt_crt = 'D' THEN sec_amount  
            WHEN dbt_crt = 'C' THEN - sec_amount
            ELSE 0
       END) as NetAMount,
```

You cannot re-use column aliases in a `SELECT`.  In addition, SQL doesn't support nested `SUM()`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are using the aggregate function twice `sum(sum.....sum..)` with the alias from the same select (It is not allowed to use aliases in the same `select`).

Just use:

```
 Sum(CASE WHEN dbt_crt = 'D' THEN sec_amount ELSE 0 END) -
 Sum(CASE WHEN  dbt_crt = 'C' THEN sec_amount ELSE 0 END)
```

or more simple way as described in other answers too:

```
 Sum(CASE WHEN dbt_crt = 'D' THEN sec_amount ELSE -1*sec_amount END)
```